# If/yield cascade - how to make more concise?

Tags: python, if-statement, yield

I have, in a function, a lot of consecutive statements like the following:

```
if condition1:
  yield x
else:
  yield None

if condition2:
  yield y
else:
  yield None

...
```

Is there a way to make more concise this kind of code?

Comment: `yield x if condition1 else None`?

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of conditions you have? Otherwise all I can think of is making it a one liner:
`yield x if condition1 else None`

Comment: Removed the switch-statement tag because Python doesn't have a switch statement, and I can't imagine how you'd expect one to help you here if it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) would make it more concise:

```
yield x if condition1 else None
yield y if condition2 else None
```

<s>Or if you have many (value, condition) pairs and don't mind evaluating all conditions up front:</s>

<s>`for val, cond in [(x, condition1), (y, condition2)]:yield val if cond else None`</s>

**Note:**  Second part of answer stricken for reasons given in comments below.

Comment: Or `yield from (value if condition else None for value, condition in blah blah)`.

Comment: Second example kind of defeats the point of generators in that all the conditions and values must be evaluated before the generator is able to produce its first value. Same for abarnert's one liner.

Comment: In the second example, there is of course a danger of shifting a substantial load in evaluating the conditions to the single statement composing the list, instead of distributing the load between the yields. Of course only the OP can know if this is an issue or not.

Comment: Don't use the for loop if you have to create a list just to have something to iterate over; it's not easier to read, and it will have an impact on performance.

Comment: @Dunes.  You and deets and chepner are correct.  Striked from answer.

Comment: @Dunes: If the conditions and values are already in variables named `x`, `y` and `condition1`, `condition2`, etc., then they're already evaluated in advance by definition. If they're in, e.g., a pair of arbitrary iterables, then you just do `yield from (value if condition else None for value, condition in zip(values, conditions))`.